# Send Values from Page to Component (NEXT.JS + LEAFLET)

Tags: javascript, next.js, leaflet

I am starting to use Next.js with Leaflet maps and I have a doubt (very newbie). I have created a page in next ( /pages/map/[id].jsx ) that makes use of a component ( /component/Map.jsx ).

From the page ( [id].jsx ) I make a fetch to a JSON file with several values among them the "Latitude and Longitude" and I need to pass those values to the component ( Map.jsx ) so that it shows in the page the map with those coordinates.

The page ( [id].jsx ) uses different values for each post. I would like to know how I can pass those values to the component.

My experience using React and Next.js is very basic, I have searched quite a bit on the internet, but have not been able to come up with the information. can anyone enlighten me the way? Thank you very much and best regards

Code of archive [id].jsx

```
import Image from "next/image";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

export default function soloRefugio({ data }) {

  return (
    <Layout>
      <article>
        <Image
          priority
          src={data[0].Imagen.name}
          height={400}
          width={400}
          alt="imagen"
        />
        <h1>{data[0].Nombre}</h1>
        <p>P: {data[0].Pro}</p>
        <p>A: {data[0].Alt}</p>
      <MapBox />
      </article>
    </Layout>
  );
}

function MapBox() {
  const Map = dynamic(
    () => import('../../components/Map'),
    { ssr: false }
  )
  return <Map />
}


export async function getStaticPaths() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/ref");
    const data = await res.json();
    const paths = data.map(({ slug }) => ({ params: { id: slug } }));

    return {
      paths,
      fallback: false,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/ref?slug=" + params.id);
    const data = await res.json();
    return {
      props: {
        data: data,
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Code of archive component Map.jsx

```
import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'

const Map = () => {

  return (
    <MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false} style={{height: 400, width: "100%"}}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
        <Popup>
          A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
    </MapContainer>
  )
}

export default Map
```

Comment: Aren't the values you want to pass inside the `data` variable? You can just pass the desired values directly to `MapBox` (and to `Map`) as props.

Comment: Also note that you should not use a `next/dynamic` import inside a component, it should be done at the top level instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in Next's [dynamic routes' documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes), you can use the hook `useRouter` to get the query parameters that you're passing to your route.

In your case, you could add to your `soloRefugio` component:

```
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id } = router.query
```